# Qt Creator use another GCC Version located in another Place

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, qt-creator

I installed a gcc 4.8.0 in the /opt folder.
I put in my PATH, so when i do a gcc/g++ -v it returns to me the 4.8.0 version.
But when i go to the QT Creator and compile my program with the c++11 code (implemented in 4.3 > ) it don't compile.
So i put a -v option in the QMAKE_CXXFLAGS flag.
So i get:

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2335.15~25/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2335.15~25/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)
```

Then i tried to create another toolchain that points to the new path, it is in Custom, but i cannot use it.
How can i force the QT Creator to use another compiler (in my case the GCC, but in another PATH)
I want to force so the XCODE dont need to change the compiler too.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Qt Creator go in

```
Tools -> Options -> Build&Run -> Compilers
```

then add a new gcc compiler.

Then go into

```
Tools -> Options -> Build&Run -> Kits
```

and change the compiler in your current kit (usually called "Desktop").

You may need latest versions of Qt Creator with "kits" (available from Qt Creator 2.6).

Comment: that's doesn't work: qmake use always g++ instead the real compiler on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Recently I came across this problem too. My raspberry pi's default gcc version is *8.3.0*, and it doesn't support c++'s `include<execution>`. I downloaded another version of gcc, which is *gcc-9.1.0*, and it’s location is `\opt\gcc-9.1.0`. I've tired to add this new compiler in `Tools-> Options -> Build&Run -> Compilers` and change settings in `kits`. When I used qmake to first generate the makefile, I noticed that it's `cxx` flag is still `gcc` in make file. When I built the project, the compiler output starts with `g++ -o ....` not `g++-9.1 -o ....`

I fixed it with the following approach:

Add `QMAKE_CXX = g++-9.1 -std=c++2a` in your `xxx.pro` file. After this, when you generate makefile again, you can see that `CXX` in makefile is set to `g++-9.1 -std=c++2a`. It will use `g++-9.1` when you build the project.